# Как объявить идентификатор? nc

Tags: visual-studio

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h> //для getchar(), putchar(), printf()
#include <conio.h> //для _getch

using namespace System;

#define eof -1 //признак конца файла

int main()

{

    long nc;
    nc=o;

    printf("Make input>\n");

    while (getchar()!=eof)

     nc++;

    printf("characters's number is: %ld\n",nc);

    _getch();
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
1>2.3_2011.cpp(13): error C2065: o: необъявленный идентификатор
```

Подскажите что делать?

Comment: может, там ноль, а не о?

Comment: @nesterenko, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если следовать написанию кода в духе

```
 #define eof -1
```

то можно добавить

```
 #define o 0
```

Comment: @avp можно я опять встряну. Человек язык не знает, а вы его препроцессором мучите )

Comment: @perfect, может, эта *шутка* подвигнет его все-таки разобраться в словах явно списанного кода.

Comment: @avp извините за резкое слово, но это медвежья услуга, он сейчас начнет, не разбираясь, все переменные так инициализировать.

Comment: Значит он не годится в программисты.

Comment: @avp вот тут я не спорю. Скорей всего, он практическую работу делает.

Answer (score 1):

в **nc = o;** букву О на нуль замените